# List seems to randomly change

Tags: python, append, filtering

I am trying to recursively create a list that also filters on already having a similar value. I cannot compare these directly as they differ at 10^-4th and further. The values need to have a minimal spacing of 0.09. 
This seems to work however, when the code runs through the loop again it seems to alter the added values.

I have tried debugging but am at a loss as to where the error occurs.It does not seem to happen at a certain event.

```
    for i in range(len(self.poses)):
        if self.poses[i].position.z > min_z:
           if min_x < abs(self.poses[i].position.x) < max_x:
            print('pos x', abs(self.poses[i].position.x))
            print('1.1')
            #max_x = self.poses[i].position.x
            if self.poses[i].position.y > 0.33:
            print('2.1')
     if self.poses[i].position.y < max_y:
        print('3.1')
        max_y = self.poses[i].position.y
        positions.x = self.poses[i].position.x
        positions.y = self.poses[i].position.y
        positions.z = self.poses[i].position.z

        if len(self.pickposes) == 0:
           print('posistion voor real cente:', positions)
           print('list empty')
           self.pickposes.append(positions)
           print(self.pickposes)
        else:
           tmp = 0
           loop_length = len(self.pickposes)
           for j in range(loop_length):
               if (abs(positions.y - self.pickposes[j].y) > 0.09):
                   print('y = ', positions.y)
                   print(j)
                   print("compared to : ", self.pickposes[j].y)
                   print('abs pose diff = ', abs(positions.y - self.pickposes[j].y))
                   tmp += 1
                   print('tmp in for loop =', tmp)

            print('tmp outside for =',tmp)
            print('loop length', loop_length)
            if loop_length <= self.index:
               if tmp == loop_length:
                  print('posistion to add to l', positions)
                  print("list of poses:", self.pickposes)
                  self.pickposes.append(positions)
                  print("list of poses:", self.pickposes)
```

I am expecting a list that consist of coordinates. None of which are in there dubbel with a rang of 9 around each one. The result i am getting is:

```
    control_node: ('list of poses:', [x: 0.540071368217
    control_node: y: 0.578928947449
    control_node: z: 1.15875029564])
    control_node: 41
    control_node: ('pos x', 0.5376651287078857)
    control_node: 1.1
    control_node: 2.1
    control_node: 3.1
    control_node: ('y = ', 0.6925374269485474)
    control_node: 0
    control_node: ('compared to : ', 0.5789289474487305)
    control_node: ('abs pose diff = ', 0.1136084794998169)
    control_node: ('tmp in for loop =', 1)
    control_node: ('tmp outside for =', 1)
    control_node: ('loop length', 1)
    control_node: ('posistion to add to l', x: 0.537665128708
    control_node: y: 0.692537426949
    control_node: z: 1.15663790703)
    control_node: ('list of poses:', [x: 0.540071368217
    control_node: y: 0.578928947449
    control_node: z: 1.15875029564])
    control_node: ('list of poses:', [x: 0.540071368217
    control_node: y: 0.578928947449
    control_node: z: 1.15875029564, x: 0.537665128708
    control_node: y: 0.692537426949
    control_node: z: 1.15663790703])
    control_node: ('pos x', 0.5400646328926086)
    control_node: 1.1
    control_node: 2.1
    control_node: 3.1
    control_node: ('tmp outside for =', 0)
    control_node: ('loop length', 2)
    control_node: ('pos x', 0.5925142168998718)
    control_node: 1.1
    control_node: ('pos x', 0.5925142168998718)
    control_node: 1.1
    control_node: ('len list of poses', 2)
    control_node: ('list of poses:', [x: 0.540071368217
    control_node: y: 0.578928947449
    control_node: z: 1.15875029564, x: 0.540064632893
    control_node: y: 0.576979875565
    control_node: z: 1.15687179565])
    control_node: 50
    control_node: 51
```

The change from

x: 0.537665128708
y: 0.692537426949
z: 1.15663790703

to 
x: 0.540064632893
y: 0.576979875565
z: 1.15687179565

Is unexpected and should not happen. The control node uses a stepper (the numbers 41, 50, 51) to maneuver through its program in the correct sequence. There is no stepper printed in between so I am quite sure that nothing has happened between the printing of the 2 lists apart from restarting the upper for loop.

Comment: Please provide example data and code to reproduce this problem

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an explanation on the behavior that was observed. It can be prevented by using copy.deepcopy('x') when appending.